# Taking the most distant value from the root in a hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to model a hierarchy of "settings", where values are defined at a root level and can be overridden by more specific children. If a child does not specify a value, its parents value should be used.

I'll use a trite example to illustrate the problem. The hierarchy here is only three levels deep, but I would like a solution that works for N levels.

Given that I am storing the information as follows:

```
id| parent_id| setting
----------------------
 1|      NULL|   false
 2|         1|    true
 3|         2|    NULL
```

What I want, from a procedural perspective, is to get a child node in a tree and if its "settings" value is NULL look at its parent for a value, recursively, until a value is found, or the root is reached. Essentially, for the information provided, I want to produce the following set, so I can attach a simple `WHERE` clause to get the applicable settings for any given `id`.

```
id| setting
-----------
 1|   false
 2|    true
 3|    true
```

I've have a view which "flattens" the hierarchy into ancestors and descendants:

```
ancestor| descendant| ancestor_setting| descendant_setting
----------------------------------------------------------
       1|          2|            false|               true
       1|          3|            false|               NULL
       2|          3|             true|               NULL
    NULL|          1|             NULL|              false
    NULL|          2|             NULL|               true
    NULL|          3|             NULL|               NULL
```

In this way, you can query all levels of the hierarchy as a set, which I hoped would be useful in getting an answer.

So far, I've only been able to select a "branch" from the tree using this view:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ancestor, descendent) id,
       CASE WHEN ancestor IS NULL THEN descendant_setting
            ELSE ancestor_setting
       END setting
FROM hierarchy
WHERE descendant = 3

id| setting
-----------
 1|   false
 2|    true
 3|    NULL
```

I've tried to think up ways to use this "flattened" structure to form a simple set of joins, and whilst I can get all the records back this way (and then filter them procedurally on a client), I want to know if there's a way to produce the expected set so that I could get back the expected settings for a single ID.

Comment: I've read through your question twice and I beleive I have @ least a partial improvement/help for you but I'm still not completely sure what you are wanting. Are you wanting a SQL query that will check both parents & children & provide you with only non-null settings? If this is true, wouldn't you also need to know if the setting was assigned to the parent or the child from the same query?

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version are you using?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: @MER What I want, from a procedural perspective, is to get a child node in a tree and if its "settings" value is `NULL` look at its parent for a value, recursively, until a value is found, or the root is reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH    RECURSIVE
        q AS
        (
        SELECT  id, parent_id, id ancestor_id, setting
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   parent_id IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  m.id, q.id, ancestor_id, COALESCE(m.setting, q.setting)
        FROM    q
        LEFT JOIN
                mytable m
        ON      m.parent_id = q.id
        WHERE   q.id IS NOT NULL
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   id IS NULL
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works or what the approach is?

Comment: @Tragedian: it's recursive query to build the transitive closure of the relationship. On each step the deepest non-null setting so far is recorded. On the last step `m.id` becomes `NULL` which allows you to filter the last step and retrieve the value.